# Multiple CREATE TABLE with errors within one transaction - no PDO exception

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo

I'm trying to create four tables within one PDO transaction.

When the first "CREATE TABLE ..." part of the statement contains errors I successfully get an exception, an error message, and rollback. But when the first "CREATE TABLE ..." part are written correctly (as in the example below) I get no exception, commit, and only the first table created.

Here's the code:

```
$conn = Connection::getInstance();

$conn->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$conn->dbh->beginTransaction();
     
$stmt = $conn->dbh->prepare("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `1st table` (valid SQL-code)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `2nd table` (SQL-code with an error)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `3rd table`...
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `4th table`...
");
try
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->dbh->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $conn->dbh->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
    
unset($stmt);
```

After some research I found the following [note](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.rollback.php) at php.net:

> Some databases, including MySQL, automatically issue an implicit COMMIT when a database definition language (DDL) statement such as DROP TABLE or CREATE TABLE is issued within a transaction.

Is it that what causes the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't execute the statements individually in succession?  I've never seen multiple statements run in a single call like that.

Comment: I want to create all the tables in a single transaction. If there are errors in SQL-code I don't want none of them to be created.

Comment: It's allowed to execute multiple PDO statements in one call. And if there are no errors in SQL-code the all four tables are created successfully.

Comment: I did a test myself and it's seems to be true that MySQL `COMMIT`s after you `CREATE TABLE`, even when inside a transaction. Following `ROLLBACK`s won't have any effect.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html There is your answer. If you want either all the tables created or none, you will have to drop created tables upon error.

Comment: hmmm, I'm creating a bunch of tables in one go, and the problem I find is that when there is an error in the sql PDO does not return false or throw of any kind of error, furthermore, errorInfo() & errorCode() will not be populated with error info. Whereas, if you exec the create table statements individually and there's an sql error, then PDE wil lreturn false and populate errorInfo() and errorCode() with error info. This has got to be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Like several commenters suggested, transactional semantics are not available for data definition language statements (DDL) in mySQL.

The PDO implementers obviously did not attempt to add some kind of client-side transactional semantics where there is no support in the DBMS.